# Problem adding Image to hyperlink in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want an image to be my hyperlink in Google sheets.

Here is my formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("google.com/de", IMAGE("http://s5.favim.com/orig/69/hi-love-quote-start-Favim.com-658946.jpg"))
```

The image shows up on the sheet - but it is no longer a hyperlink.

Comment: Apparently, this is impossible in the New Google Sheets, but I don't have a reference to prove this.

Comment: Did you try to prepend url with `http://`? This [worked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176203/make-image-clickable-in-google-spreadsheet/27370989#comment63449229_27370989) for me.

Answer (score -2):

You're right in thinking that this is a hyperlink. But I think that you've got broken code.

Try something like this:

```
=HYPERLINK ( "URL" ;   IMAGE( "logo3w.png" ) )
```

You missed out the `;`.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BjnpMxEdbcI)

Comment: When I use the semicolon, it auto corrects back to a comma... same thing happens.

Comment: Semi-colons in functions as an parameter separator are used in countries like France that use commas for other things. In the U.S., we use commas.

Comment: Well in either case, both semi colons AND commas are not working for me

Comment: That source is from 2011, referring to old version of Google sheets. As others said, ; vs , is just a matter of locale.